# C++ Reading file with really long text

Tags: c++

I have following C++ code that is supposed to read from this [file](http://pastebin.com/twALa8bz) . I want to capture the IP and PORT from the text file and write it into a file. I have done following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("myfile.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        cout<<line;
        if(line.find("IP")){
            cout<<line;
        }
        if(line.find("PORT")){
            cout<<line;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

But I am not getting correct output. What am I doing wrong here? I want to get those IP and PORT values and write another text file with following contents.

```
{
"ip":"127.0.0.1",
"port":"9999"
}
```

What should I be doing to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
std::size_t loc = line.find("IP");
if(loc != std::string::npos) {
  cout << line.substr(loc);
}
```

Do similar for the port also.

[std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) returns the location of first character offset where the string was found or `std::string::npos` if string is not found.

Comment: Can you look at the text file I attached with the question

Comment: [No, it works perfectly fine](http://ideone.com/iqa2fb). Follow the link and browse to the end of page to check the output.

Comment: Mohit the code works fine in Ideone but when I merge this in my C++ file, it doesn't produce the required info. If it were, I would have marked this as answer.

Comment: It appears then the error is somewhere else. (Possibly while merging).

Comment: Could you make the program work when adding your code and reading file line rather than cin

Comment: `cin` and any file are both `std::istream`. All you need to do is: `std::ifstream myfile ("myfile.txt");` And replace `cin` with `myfile`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65273/discussion-between-sarvagya-pant-and-mohit-jain).